# Is there a way to print an assert only once at the beggining of a simulation in vhdl?

Tags: report, vhdl

I have a vhdl entity which I instanciate in a testbench.

I would like it to print a report just once at the beginning of the simulation to show which generic was used.

Is that possible with synthetisable code ?

Thanks,

SLP

Comment: Historically IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 RTL Synthesis (withdrawn) required assertion and report statements to be ignored. An entity declarative part can have a  passive process with assertion/report statements with a final wait statement with no timeout/condition/sensiivity clauses. It will execute once during initialization. A similar process statement can be placed in an architecture body or block statement statement part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
process
begin
    report "Integer parameter FOO value = " & integer'image(FOO);
    wait;
end process;
```

Caution on the `wait;` statement! As @user1155120 notes, processes without a sensitivity list will loop infinitely, unless stopped with a `wait;` statement.